# What is the "static" backend type in EAV attribute Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, database, sql, eav-attributes

In the "eav_attribute" table I discovered that some attributes have the backend type set to "static".

Example, *attribute_code = 'telephone' & entity_type_id = 2*
 resulted in a "static" backend type. Furthermore, most of the attributes *entity_type_id = 2* are set to 'static'. (in my db id 2 is for address attributes)

What type does this value represent? Should I use it instead of using 'varchar' for similar attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static attributes are attributes stored in the main table of an entity - for catalog products, `catalog_product_entity`. For example, the attribute sku of catalog products is defined as `static`. Static attributes are always loaded by Magento, and are useful especially if you want to retrieve information quickly or to optimize lookup of data. A drawback of this type of attributes is that you can't have store-specific values, which is one of the advantages of Magento EAV system.

Even if you define an attribute as static, Magento won't treat it as such unless you have a corresponding column in the main entity table. If the column is not there, Magento treats the attribute as `varchar` by default and looks for it in the varchar EAV table for the model - for products, `catalog_product_entity_varchar`.

If you want to use static attributes in your project, you have to do 2 things in your install/upgrade scripts. First, you need to add a column to the main entity table, with the correct column definition. Next, you need to install your attribute using the `addAttribute()` method, and define your attribute as static.

If you plan to run often queries based on your custom static attributes, consider adding an `index` on the new column to speed up data fetching.

You can check the detailed MySql version answer on

> https://mage2.pro/t/topic/655
>
> https://blog.magestore.com/magento-certificate-databases-tables-for-eav-entities/