# Magento2 static attributes and varchar attributes

Tags: magento2

What can be said about both static attributes and varchar attributes?

> 1. Can have exactly the same value at all store levels
> 2. Can have different values at all store levels
> 3. Can have backend_component
> 4. Can be created via the admin

as per me, it is 1 and 3 ..can anyone else suggest?

Comment: Do you need to know which options are correct for static and varchar product type?

Comment: what are "static attributes" supposed to be?

Comment: @aravind Yes...

Comment: @PhilippSander those are data type static and varchar for eg; SKU which has static datatype in database

Comment: static is not a datatype. SKUs are varchar. Prove: "SHOW COLUMNS FROM `catalog_product_entity` where Field = 'sku'"

Comment: where exactly did you see that static is a datatype? please provide a link to the documentation or a file

Comment: @PhilippSander https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/286994/what-is-the-static-backend-type-in-eav-attribute-magento-2/286995#286995

Comment: Other option is We can set custom backend model for both.?
Can you please suggest me what would be right answer?